# How to set cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 in RCurl

Tags: r, libcurl, rcurl

Using RCurl getURL() to download data I get errors like

```
SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

As I read, this might be related to the `ssl.cipher.list` option within the curl options.

If so, how can I set ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 as cipher?

For me

`curlOptions(ssl.cipher.list = "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384",...)`

and other things tried out did not work.

Here my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.11 bitops_1.0-6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.2.0
```

If more details are required please let me know.

Update:

This is the output for `curl::curl_version()` version on R:

```
> curl::curl_version()
$`version`
[1] "7.59.0"

$ssl_version
[1] "(OpenSSL/1.0.2n) WinSSL"

$libz_version
[1] "1.2.8"

$libssh_version
[1] "libssh2/1.8.0"

$libidn_version
[1] NA

$host
[1] "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

$protocols
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"   "ldaps"  "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtsp"   "scp"    "sftp"  
[17] "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"  

$ipv6
[1] TRUE

$http2
[1] FALSE

$idn
[1] TRUE
```

This is the output of `RCurl::curlVersion()`

```
RCurl::curlVersion()
$`age`
[1] 3

$version
[1] "7.40.0"

$vesion_num
[1] 468992

$host
[1] "x86_64-pc-win32"

$features
      ssl      libz      ntlm asynchdns    spnego largefile       idn      sspi 
        4         8        16       128       256       512      1024      2048 

$ssl_version
[1] "OpenSSL/1.0.0o"

$ssl_version_num
[1] 0

$libz_version
[1] "1.2.8"

$protocols
 [1] "dict"   "file"   "ftp"    "ftps"   "gopher" "http"   "https"  "imap"   "imaps"  "ldap"   "pop3"   "pop3s"  "rtmp"   "rtsp"   "scp"    "sftp"  
[17] "smtp"   "smtps"  "telnet" "tftp"  

$ares
[1] ""

$ares_num
[1] 0

$libidn
[1] ""
```

On Windows itself the following is installed but most likely not used by R.
From git bash:

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.60.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.60.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 nghttp2/1.32.0
```

Output of `jsonlite::fromJSON(RCurl::getURL("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check", .opts = opts))`

```
> jsonlite::fromJSON(RCurl::getURL("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check", .opts = opts))
$`given_cipher_suites`
 [1] "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"  "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"     
 [4] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA" "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA"
 [7] "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"     "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"   "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"         
[10] "TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA"     "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" 
[13] "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"      "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"      "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA"        
[16] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA"         "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA" "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA"
[19] "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"     "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"   "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"         
[22] "TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA"             "TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA"     "TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA"            
[25] "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"   "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"    
[28] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"     "TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"    "TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA" 
[31] "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"         "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"    

$ephemeral_keys_supported
[1] TRUE

$session_ticket_supported
[1] FALSE

$tls_compression_supported
[1] FALSE

$unknown_cipher_suite_supported
[1] FALSE

$beast_vuln
[1] FALSE

$able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting
[1] TRUE

$insecure_cipher_suites
named list()

$`tls_version`
[1] "TLS 1.0"

$rating
[1] "Bad"
```

Output of `httr::content(httr::GET("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check"))`

```
> httr::content(httr::GET("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check"))
$`given_cipher_suites`
$`given_cipher_suites`[[1]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[2]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[3]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[4]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[5]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[6]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[7]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[8]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[9]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[10]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[11]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[12]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[13]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[14]]
[1] "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[15]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[16]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[17]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[18]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[19]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[20]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[21]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[22]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[23]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[24]]
[1] "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[25]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"

$`given_cipher_suites`[[26]]
[1] "TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5"


$ephemeral_keys_supported
[1] TRUE

$session_ticket_supported
[1] FALSE

$tls_compression_supported
[1] FALSE

$unknown_cipher_suite_supported
[1] FALSE

$beast_vuln
[1] FALSE

$able_to_detect_n_minus_one_splitting
[1] FALSE

$insecure_cipher_suites
$insecure_cipher_suites$`TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`
$insecure_cipher_suites$`TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`[[1]]
[1] "uses 3DES which is vulnerable to the Sweet32 attack but was not configured as a fallback in the ciphersuite order"


$insecure_cipher_suites$TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
$insecure_cipher_suites$TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA[[1]]
[1] "uses 3DES which is vulnerable to the Sweet32 attack but was not configured as a fallback in the ciphersuite order"


$insecure_cipher_suites$TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
$insecure_cipher_suites$TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5[[1]]
[1] "uses RC4 which has insecure biases in its output"


$insecure_cipher_suites$TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
$insecure_cipher_suites$TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA[[1]]
[1] "uses RC4 which has insecure biases in its output"



$tls_version
[1] "TLS 1.2"

$rating
[1] "Bad"
```

Comment: What version of `libcurl` is on your system/what was `RCurl` built with? What is the output of `jsonlite::fromJSON(RCurl::getURL("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check"))` (put it in a code block)? Compare it with the output of `httr::content(httr::GET("https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check"))`. If the latter has a more updated `libcurl` with support for the more modern ciphers then try moving to it vs stay with `RCurl`

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks for your answer. Yes, there is a difference between RCurl and httr. Please see update in original question.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. So, it looks like your RCurl was built with an [almost 4 year old version of `libcurl`](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_40_0) and that's the latest RCurl on CRAN (`1.95-4.11`). You're going to have to try to translate whatever you were doing to `curl` or `httr`.

Comment: Yes, guess thats my only option but seeing all this httr might be the better option anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question based on a comment from @hrbrmstr above.

**So, it looks like your RCurl was built with an almost 4 year old version of libcurl and that's the latest RCurl on CRAN (1.95-4.11)**

I decided to switch from `RCurl` to `httr` and got a result right away, meaning I'm now able to download data from the desired ftp server.

I compared the output of `RCurl::listCurlOptions()` against `httr::httr_options()` which made it more easy for me to find the right variable names to use for the curl options.

Hope this answer helps others that run into same issues with RCurl.

Comment: great summary and I'm glad that worked! Don't forget to accept your own answer (whenver that timer ends)!